# Outlook email - SMTPLIB - Can't send emails

Tags: python, outlook, smtplib

I'm creating a script that sends emails with my outlook email that have the following SMTP settings:

```
Servername: smtp.office365.com
Port: 587
Protocol command: STARTTLS
```

For that I was using the following code:

```
client = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
client.ehlo()
client.starttls()
client.ehlo()
client.login(user, password)
client.sendmail(msg['From'], emaillist , msg.as_string())
client.close()
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
(554, b'5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:OutboundSpamException; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message WASCL UserAction verdict is not None. Actual verdict is HipNotify. OutboundSpamException: WASCL UserAction verdict is not None. Actual verdict is HipNotify. [Hostname=DB8P191MB0809.EURP191.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]')
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: On my case, I didn't receive any automatically email with some instructions

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine- this is an email server error message rather than a Python exception. For some reason (probably to stop automated programs sending spam) your email host is blocking your email.

[This github thread here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/issues/519) suggests that you can fix the issue by logging in confirming your identity.